# Caman was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, html, camanjs

In my HTML I have the following scripts in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/caman.full.js"></script>
```

and in my Javascript file (scripts.js) I tried to do the following code snippet:

```
Caman("#myImage", function () {
this.brightness(5);
}
```

As the title says, I get the error `Caman was used before it was defined`. I'm not sure if there's something obvious that I'm missing or doing incorrectly, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you including it twice?

Comment: And where/when are you including *your* Javascript? (once you settle on the minified or non-minified version of caman.full.js)

Comment: can you reverse the script tags?

Comment: Yep. When `scripts.js` is loaded, unless there's a `document.ready()` handler in there that we can't see, `Caman` hasn't been included (and therefore hasn't been defined) yet.

Comment: I have a `document.ready()` handler but at the minute it contains miscellaneous functions not relating to the Caman stuff

Comment: Then it's the obvious thing. First include/define the `Caman` stuff. *Then* use it.

Comment: I read the documentation but unless I completely missed something (Which is probably the case), I'm not sure what I need to do to define `Caman` in the `document.ready()` handler

Comment: No one's suggesting that. See your two `<script>` tags up there? Reverse them. First `caman.full.js`, then `scripts.js`.

Comment: Oh, I swapped them around already but the same thing occurs; `Caman was used before it was defined` and also `Missing new` referring to the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The Caman script needs to be included first like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/caman.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Then in your script you are missing the last `);`:

```
Caman("#myImage", function () {
this.brightness(5);
});
```

If that doesn't work there may be something else in your code that is causing problems.

Comment: For the line `Caman("#myImage", function () ` it tells me `Missing 'new'` for some reason